# matlab function definition in properties

Tags: matlab, function, properties

I have a function like:

```
properties
maxIterations=2000;
treesMax = 30;
lim=[-5 +5;-5 +5 ;-5 +5];
start=[?????];
goal =[2 3 2];
nsmooth=1000;
figure_h = [];
axis_h = [];
end
```

but my `start` value depends on a function like `start=ForwardKin(DHtab, dof)` which is defined in another m-file.

How can I define it in properties? I use someone else's code that's why I have to implement that code to `properties`

Comment: Exactly how you have it written. `start=ForwardKin(DHtab, dof)`. Just ensure `ForwardKin` is in your current working directory or in [MATLAB's path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html)

Comment: What is properties? Is that the (uncommented) header of the section or the name of an m-file?